# Property 'people' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular

I try to create a tabelau with the data of my API inside, but I get an error on the "people" "Property 'people' does not exist on type 'Object' " at line 19 and 20  while the latter is present in the API

do you have solution

here my code

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserModel } from './model/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  users: UserModel[] = [];

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log(1);
    this.readAPI('https://**REMOVED FOR PRIVACY**/people')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(3);
        this.users = data.people;
        console.log(data, data.people);
      });
    console.log(2);
  }

  readAPI(URL: string) {
    return this.http.get(URL);
  }


}
```

Comment: For starters, you might want to remove your API url, unless you're cool with folks harvesting all that data with names, emails, addresses, gender etc (You just broke a lot of GDPR bro). In fact, I'll do that for you after I leave this comment. Instead just provide a short mock data example. Second, where are you instantiating tableu? What is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick unblock, do this:

```
.subscribe((data: any) => {...
```

You can replace `any` with an interface that the method will return for a better solution.